# Saved draft in Android app after question submitted

Tags: bug, asking-questions, android-app, draft

I wrote a question in the Android app and posted it. Came back a few minutes later and went to write another question. It told me that I had a saved draft and asked if I wanted to resume. When I clicked yes, it showed me the text of the question that I had submitted already.

Expectation: posting question clears saved draft in app.

Comment: I know it's an old issue, but are you still facing this issue? If yes, then consider putting the app version, and perhaps including device model and Android version. Otherwise, feel free to self-answer/flag as no-repro to close this bug report.